# Import symmetric key into Android Keystore (key generated externally)

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore

I import a symmetric key into the Android Keystore with the following code, as illustrated in this example: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/security/keystore/KeyProtection

```
  final SecretKey aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(myKeyByteArray, 0, myKeyByteArray.length, "AES");
  final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
  keyStore.load(null);
  keyStore.setEntry(
          "my_key_alias",
          new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(aesKey),
          new KeyProtection.Builder(KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
         .setBlockMode(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)         
         .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
         .build());
```

One could also generate a random AES key with the following code:

```
final KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGenerator.init(AES_KEY_LEN);
final SecretKey aesKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
....
```

Note that this KeyGenerator does not generate a key within secure hardware. It just generates a random key within the app process.

How can I import an externally generated symmetric keys into the Android key store?
Do I need to resort to some workarounds with a public-private key pair to encrypt the symmetric key?

**EDIT**: There are no workarounds necessary. It is possible to import an externally generated key into the Android Keystore with the above code.